# Is it possible to set up inter cluster tls termination with Kubernetes resources?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

Context: I'm setting up a mutating admission controller webhook in my cluster, and the webhook needs to be addressed as https, not http. To make this work, I've been using the cert and private key loaded into the containers running on my pods, and performing tls termination in the service there. This works, but I would rather do the tls termination outside of the application itself, mostly for ease of updating, then just run my application at http and proxy to it with my service. Is it possible to set up some combination of ingress/service that will perform tls termination **inside the cluster**? I know that it's possible to do this when setting up an external ingress, but this is internal traffic, and I definitely want to keep it that way.

Comment: Is there anything that you tried already? Can you share some of your configs?

Comment: No, I can't find information on anything to try, I'm looking for ideas.